# How to trace total in/out bandwidth used by users in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

After some researching, I have discovered that there is a spring actuator project which is used to monitor and log information about the application. Here is the link that suggests how to put log in to my own custom repository for post processing. [http://www.sedooe.com/2017/08/tracing-requests-and-responses-with-spring-boot-actuator/ ]

However, the total in/out byte counts are not included. I know that I can try to wrap `HttpServeletRequest` and `HttpServeletResponse` (in the filter, pass them to the filter chain so that it can count in/out throughput whenever they are consumed or written out) which will return custom `SerlvetInputStream` and `ServletOutputStream` that can count the number of bytes.

This seems to be a common problem in business application and there should already be a solution so I wonder if there is any easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the Spring-Boot 1.5 actuator implementation doesn't provide such a functionality. (Assuming you are talking about Spring-Boot 1.5.)

What you could do is having a look at the [Micrometer](https://micromter.io) project. It's the new actuator metrics "backend" for Spring-Boot 2.0. In case you are still using Spring-Boot 1.5 you can use the `micrometer-spring-legacy` library in your app.

Key thing to understand here is that for Spring-Boot 1.5 this is a metric backend which is living next to the "old" actuator.

What the project provides is instrumentation for embedded [`Jetty`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jetty/JettyStatisticsMetrics.java) and [`Tomcat`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/tomcat/TomcatMetrics.java) server. Allthough only the latter does provide in and out traffic metrics.

Assuming `Tomcat`, you'll get `tomcat_global_received_bytes_total` and `tomcat_global_sent_bytes_total` metrics over which you can reason about in your favorite monitoring system.